# How to recycle data in an SqlDataSource object?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sqldatasource

I have an `SqlDataSource` object, linked to a `GridView`, which receives data from a database when executed.

I'd like to add the values of the "*Cost*" column, to get the *"TotalCost"*, and place it in a `TextBox` or Label on top of the `GridView`.

Is it possible to just use (recycle) the data in the `SqlDataSource` object, instead of using another `SqlDataSource` object to just get the *TotalCost*"?

Answer (score 1):

If you handle the rowdatabound event you can get the values from each row to get your total.

Comment: Should note that it's the rowdatabound event on the gridview just to avoid any confusion.